# Cannot move my avatar in spritekit in playground

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

I am recently trying to build a game using spriteKit and I want to move my avatar to to my touch position and all the other enemy's to my avatar's current position.But my avatar is not moving from its position and is only rotating in the direction to where I touch. I want to move it to my touch position. Here is my code:
"'

import SpriteKit

public class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

```
let playerSpeed: CGFloat = 40.0
let coronaSpeed: CGFloat = 10.0

var mask: SKSpriteNode?
var player: SKSpriteNode?
var mcorona: [SKSpriteNode] = []

var lastTouch: CGPoint? = nil

override public func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    // Animations
    player = childNode(withName: "player") as? SKSpriteNode

    mask = childNode(withName: "mask") as? SKSpriteNode
    mask!.run(SKAction.repeatForever(
        SKAction.sequence([
            SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 10, duration: 0.45),
            SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: -10, duration: 0.45)
            ]
    )))

    for child in self.children {
        if child.name == "corona" {
            if let child = child as? SKSpriteNode {
                mcorona.append(child)
            }
        }
    }
    // </> Animations
}
override public func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,with event: UIEvent?) { handleTouches(touches) }

override public func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,with event: UIEvent?) { handleTouches(touches) }

override public func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) { handleTouches(touches) }

fileprivate func handleTouches(_ touches: Set<UITouch>) { lastTouch = touches.first?.location(in: self) }

override public func didSimulatePhysics() {
    if player != nil {
        updatePlayer()
        updateZombies()
    }
}
fileprivate func updatePosition(for sprite: SKSpriteNode, to target: CGPoint, speed: CGFloat) {

    let currentPosition = sprite.position
    let angle = CGFloat.pi + atan2(currentPosition.y - target.y, currentPosition.x - target.x)
    let rotateAction = SKAction.rotate(toAngle: angle + (CGFloat.pi*0.5), duration: 0)
    sprite.run(rotateAction)

    let velocityX = speed * cos(angle)
    let velocityY = speed * sin(angle)

    let newVelocity = CGVector(dx: velocityX, dy: velocityY)
    sprite.physicsBody?.velocity = newVelocity
}

fileprivate func gameOver(_ didWin: Bool) {
    let resultScene = MenuScene(size: size, didWin: didWin, levelToSend: 2)
    let transition = SKTransition.flipVertical(withDuration: 1.0)
    view?.presentScene(resultScene, transition: transition)
}


fileprivate func shouldMove(currentPosition: CGPoint,
                            touchPosition: CGPoint) -> Bool {
    guard let player = player else { return false }
    return abs(currentPosition.x - touchPosition.x) > player.frame.width / 2 ||
        abs(currentPosition.y - touchPosition.y) > player.frame.height / 2
}

fileprivate func updatePlayer() {
    guard let player = player,
        let touch = lastTouch
        else { return }
    let currentPosition = player.position
    if shouldMove(currentPosition: currentPosition,
                  touchPosition: touch) {
        updatePosition(for: player, to: touch, speed: playerSpeed)
    } else {
        player.physicsBody?.isResting = true
    }
}

func updateZombies() {
    guard let player = player else { return }
    let targetPosition = player.position

    for corona in mcorona {
        updatePosition(for: corona, to: targetPosition, speed: coronaSpeed)
    }
}


public func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    // Check contact
    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == player?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask &&
        secondBody.categoryBitMask == mcorona[0].physicsBody?.categoryBitMask {
        // Player & corona
        gameOver(false)
    } else if firstBody.categoryBitMask == player?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask &&
        secondBody.categoryBitMask == mask?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask {
        // Player & mask
        gameOver(true)
    }
}
```

"'
[Here is the GIF to the problem I faced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvbGn.gif)

PLS HELP!
THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are creating a new velocity and assigning it to your player, however you are not updating your players position in your code as far as I can see. Try adding a line actually updating the players position in your updatePosition function.

```
sprite.position += sprite.physicsBody.velocity
```

This would increment the sprites position for each iteration through the function updatePosition, running until the players position reaches its destination, as far as I am aware.

Another possible solution:

You could try moving the sprite using SKActions. Replace the last line in your updatePosition function to this:

```
let moveToTouch = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: target.x, y: target.y), duration: speed)

sprite.run(moveToTouch)
```

Comment: I have done it using the shouldMove function to detect my touchPosition as my final position . Also I tried your way too, but it won't run

Comment: Added another possible solution above

Comment: I guess this made some progress but not quite there. Not able to attain player speed. the enemy is moving towards the player but it appears that they are just moving with a small velocity .

Comment: here is a GIF that depicts the scenario-https://gph.is/g/aK5pnp6

Comment: also if the enemy and my avatar collide, it doesn't detect collision and overlaps on each other.

Comment: found the solution ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61744489/cannot-move-my-avatar-at-my-own-defined-speed/61767362#61767362 ... Thanks